# Python trimming a non-standard segment in a string

Tags: python, regex, list, bioinformatics, fasta

How does one remove a header from a long string of text?

I have a program that displays a FASTA file as

```
...TCGATCATCGATCG>IonTorrenttrimmedcontig1$CCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAG...
```

The string is large and contains multiple headers like this

So the headers that need to be trimmed start with a > and end with a $
There's multiple headers, ranging from IonTorrenttrimmedcontig1 to IonTorrenttrimmedcontig25

How can I cut on the > and the $, remove everything inbetween, and seperate the code before and after into seperate list elements?

The file is read from a standard FASTA file, so I´d be very happy to hear possible solutions on the input step as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is part of fasta file, so you are going to slice it like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "TCGATCATCGATCG>IonTorrenttrimmedcontig1$CCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAG"
>>> re.split(">[^$]*\$", a)
['TCGATCATCGATCG', 'CCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAG']
```

Also, some people are answering with slicing with '>ion1'. That's totally wrong!

I believe your problem is solved! I am also editing a tag with bioinformatics for this question!

Comment: That's not totally wrong if you don't know what a fasta file is, and if your example is a string containing `>ion1` (cause I didn't want to copy/paste). By the way, the regexp I was using was `">io[^$]*\$"` so why would that not be ok? (providing that user3264274 can do a little work and capitalize the i to match his example?

Comment: That would be too specific and would work only for this case! Even why the questioner would capitalize i? Make something that is robust and works for anything. 

By the way, I know and work with fasta files for almost 10 years :)

Cheers!

Comment: "The string is large and contains multiple headers _like this_" I don't work with fasta files, so I don't know the structure. But I think that a questioner can do a little bit of work. I don't want to give a man a fish… Although from the question, it's clear that it was from `>` and `$`, that you were right, and so I edited my answer ;]

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. It seems I have some re homework to do. Works exactly as described and provides me a good example, I now understand how to solve such a problem.

I also entered a name for myself, as a way to show/pledge to take part in this community!

Comment: No problem, @Roeben! Welcome to Stackoverflow, the place for us to learn and grow :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `re` module for that:

```
>>> s = "blablabla>ion1$foobar>ion2$etc>ion3$..."
>>> import re
>>> re.split(">[^$]*\$",s)
['blablabla', 'foobar', 'etc', '...']
```

And if you have 1 string on each line:

```
>>> with open("foo.txt", "r") as f:
...   for line in f:
...     re.split(">[^$]*\$",line[:-1])
... 
['blablabla', 'foobar', 'etc', '...']
['fofofofofo', 'barbarbar', 'blablabla']
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are reading over every line there a few ways to do this. You could use partition (partition returns a list containing 3 elements: [the text before the specified string, the specified string, and the text after]):

```
for line in file:
    stripped_header = line.partition(">")[2].partition("$")[0]
```

You could use split:

```
for line in file:
    stripped_header = line.spilt(">")[1].split("$")[0]
```

You could loop over all the elements in the string and only append after you pass ">" but before "$" (however this will not be nearly as efficient):

```
for line in file:
    bool = False
    stripped_header = ""
    for char in line:
        if char == ">":
            bool = True
        elif bool:
            if char != "$":
                stripped_header += char
            else:
                bool = False
```

Or alternatively use a regular expression, but it seems like my peers have already beat me to it!